# How to insert homepage and current page in breadcrumbs?

Tags: seo, google, breadcrumbs

I'm working on breadcrumbs for a client's website, and I'm asking myself if homepage has to be in its code.

I'm mostly concerned by SEO, not really for users navigation.

So, is it better to do :

**With link to homepage and current**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Accueil</span>
    </a>
    >
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Annonces</span>
    </a>
    > 
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Categorie</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category/produit" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Produit</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Without link to homepage and current page**

```
<a href="http://someclient.fr/" itemprop="url">Accueil</a> >
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Annonces</span>
    </a>
    > 
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Category</span>
    </a>
</div>
<a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category/produit" itemprop="url">Produit</a>
```

You can try this codes with Google Structured Data Testing Tool (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and you will see that homepage is not rendered with my first example.

So, what's the best solution ? How do you do for your sites ?

Thanks !

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer to this question, its down to personal user experience. Your best of asking this kind of question on UX Stack.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I asked a moderator if it's possible to move this question to UX Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing, I think, is that you have an obvious link to the homepage SOMEWHERE in the page header.

So, if the logo is already linked to the homepage, you don't need a second link in the breadcrumbs, and you're better of saving the space for other crumbs.

Since you said you're more concerned about SEO, it only matters if the homepage is linked **at least once** in the header -- and the logo is the most appropriate place to put such a link.

Comment: Is it really user-friendly ? (I mean, for users who don't know that there's a link on the logo).

Comment: I myself always expect the header logo to take me to the home page, on my sites and any I happen to visit. It's pretty conventional.

Comment: For you, yes. But for my grandpa, I don't assume it's the same.

Comment: Every major news site uses their header logo as a link back to the home. Some of them also include a text "home" link, some don't. I think it depends on how valuable that real estate is to you. But you can always put the site in front of your grandpa and watch him use it if you want to know for sure.

Comment: That's true. I think I'm gonna keep only one link in the header, on the logo. Thanks for your reply and your comments, I think my grandpa will appreciate this a lot. :-)